# Invisible Ajax errors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache2

I'm developing a website and a recurrent problem makes me lose a lot of time.

Sometimes, when using Ajax to get informations from the server, I get errors, reported by the following Javascript code:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(
        "Error in ajaxRequest\n"
        + "Status : " + textStatus 
        + "\nError: " + errorThrown
    );
}
```

The alert gives something like

```
Error in ajaxRequest
Status : parsererror
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data
```

But nothing seems wrong when I write in a file the data (just before it is sent back to client).

And Apache's error.log reports nothing.

When this occurs, I usually spend a lot of time commenting/uncommenting some code to see when the error occurs, but it's not practical at all (and very slow).

Is there a way to track those errors ? I didn't find on internet.

KR
Zlotz

Comment: You should do more debugging. Look to your [devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) console, and network tabs about what exactly is coming back from the server. My guess is php warnings or notices are being added which cause json parse errors.

Comment: I didn't know these tabs (I'm a web autodidcat) and I found straight away with them. You're a great man IncredibleHat.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Why ? For the client not to be interrupted ?

Comment: With the knowledge of devtools, you can spew so much more into console with `console.log()` than trying to put into `alert()`. You can even output whole javascript objects into console, that lets you navigate its structure with flip-opens and drilling. Console is wondrous :D

Comment: OK but in fact I already use the browser's debuggers (which do this without I have to write anything in the code). And, at least in test environment, I prefer to be clearly informed when there is an issue (my developer panel isn't always open). But I can listen to other arguments.